# need help on operator << overloading functions

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

The error I'm getting right now is:

> multiple definition of `operator<<(std::ostream&, SingleSequence& s)`

the error location is at one of the overload operator function:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SingleSequence& s)
{
    os << s.name << " " << s.seq << " " << s.length << " " << s.gccontent << " " << s.type;
    return os;
}
```

This is the driver part:

```
 #include"Sequences.h"
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <ctime>
 #include <cstdlib>

 using namespace std;

 int main(){

 cout << "Assignment #1" << endl;

Sequences mysequences;
cout << mysequences;
cout << "Sorted by name" << endl;
mysequences.sortByName();
cout << mysequences;
cout << "Sorted by length" << endl;
mysequences.sortByLength();
cout << mysequences;
cout << "... done!" << endl;
 }
```

---

This is the Sequences.h

```
#ifndef SEQUENCES_H_
#define SEQUENCES_H_
#include<string.h>
#include<strings.h>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


enum sequenceType { dna, rna, protein };
 struct SingleSequence{
    std::string name;
    std::string seq;
    int length;
    double gccontent;
    sequenceType type;


};

class Sequences {

public:


Sequences();
virtual ~Sequences();
int getListSize() const{return datasize;}
 const SingleSequence& get( int i) const{
    if (i>=0 && i < datasize)
                return data[i];
            throw OUT_OF_BOUNDS;;//{ if (i>=0 && i < datasize)
 }
//        return data[i];
//    throw OUT_OF_BOUNDS;} // C++ has exceptions - you can even throw ints;
void sortByName();
void sortByLength();
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SingleSequence& s)  ;
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Sequences& seqs) ;
int datasize;

private:
/*
 * Remember to keep all data members private
 */
static const int MAX_LIST_SIZE = 20;
SingleSequence data[MAX_LIST_SIZE];

static const int OUT_OF_BOUNDS = -1;


};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SingleSequence& s)
 { os << s.name << " " << s.seq << " " 
     << s.length << " " << s.gccontent << " "<<s.type;  
  return os;
  }
#endif /* SEQUENCES_H_ */
 -------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the main cpp file

```
#include "Sequences.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Sequences::Sequences() {

    data[0] = { "KCNH2 Primer Pair 1 Forward", "CCAACTGGTGGACCGTCATT", 20, 55.0, dna };
    data[1] = { "KCNH2 Primer Pair 1 Reverse", "GACAGCCAGGTGAACATCCA", 20, 55.0, dna };
    data[2] = { "KCNH2 Primer Pair 2 Forward", "TGGATGTTCACCTGGCTGTC", 20, 55.0, dna };
    data[3] = { "KCNH2 Primer Pair 2 Reverse", "CCACGGAACCTCTGGCAATA", 20, 55.0, dna };
    data[4] = { "KCNH2 Primer Pair 3 Forward", "GAACGGAAGTGTGCCAACTG", 20, 55.0, dna };
    data[5] = { "KCNH2 Primer Pair 3 Reverse", "ACAGCCAGGTGAACATCCAG", 20, 55.0, dna };
    data[6] = { "KCNH2 Primer Pair 4 Forward", "CTGGATGTTCACCTGGCTGT", 20, 55.0, dna };
    data[7] = { "KCNH2 Primer Pair 4 Reverse", "ATTTCCACGGAACCTCTGGC", 20, 55.0, dna };
    data[8] = { "KCNH2 Primer Pair 5 Forward", "TGAAAACCGCTCGTCTGC", 18, 55.6, dna };
    data[9] = { "KCNH2 Primer Pair 5 Reverse", "GGTGGAGCATGTGTTGTT", 18, 50.0, dna };

    datasize = 10;

    }

void Sequences::sortByName(){
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    //int flag = 1;
    SingleSequence temp;
     for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){

      if (data[j].name.compare(data[j+1].name) > 0){
         temp = data[j+1];
         data[j+1] = data[j];
         data[j] = temp;
   }
        }
      }
   }

   void Sequences::sortByLength(){
     for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++){

            SingleSequence temp1;
            for(int b = 0; b < 9; b++){
                if (data[b].length > data[b+1].length){
                         temp1 = data[b+1];
                         data[b+1] = data[b];
                         data[b] = temp1;
            }

         }
        }
    }

  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Sequences& seqs)
  {os << "  Sequences object " << endl;
  for (int i=0; i < seqs.getListSize(); i++ )
      os << "    " << (i+1) <<":  " << seqs.get( i ) << endl;
  return os;

  }
```

Comment: You have two copies of your function being linked. One's in the implementation that includes the header and the other's in the main file that includes the header.

Answer (score 1):

You have two definition of the same operator `<<` function in .h and .cpp. Hence, multi-definition error.

Keep the declaration in .h. Makes sure it is outside of the class

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SingleSequence& s);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Sequences& seqs);
```

And write the definition in you .cpp file

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Sequences& seqs)
{
  os << "  Sequences object " << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < seqs.getListSize(); i++)
     os << "    " << (i + 1) << ":  " << seqs.get(i) << endl;
  return os;
}


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SingleSequence& s)
{
  os << s.name << " " << s.seq << " "
   << s.length << " " << s.gccontent << " " << s.type;
  return os;
}
```

Comment: Those two definition are for different purpose. the one     std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SingleSequence& s);    is for the struct SingaleSequence. The other one is for Sequence object. Do you mean that I should only keep one?